# packet sniffer to show sending app

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, networking

I'm android developer and normally monitor packets by WiFi+Fiddler in my laptop in order to inspect developing app communication.

Curiously, my phone (LG G2 Jellybean, Codename LG-F320S) continuously access http://www.un.org site with no reason, but don't know which app sends it.

Several android packet sniffers show data packet itself, but do not give *which app* send the data. Is it possible to know the sender app?

Comment: Technically, this is well possible. You didn't name which sniffers you've already used (maybe my list [Sniffer, Spoofer & Portscanner](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=104) can give you alternatives). You might consider asking for a specific app at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). How to do this "programmatically" is rather off-topic here as being a development question. But let's see if any other end-user friendly solution turns up here.

Comment: @Izzy I mean, I'm finding the *app to display which packet is from which app*. I tried tPacketCapture and no luck. Of course I can understand why those kind of method cannot acheive my requirement.

Comment: I understood that (as that was the missing component if you could see the package content). I didn't play much with this, so I've got to pass on the answer; all I can give are pointers, which I did. Sorry I can't help any better.

Comment: @Izzy you're welcome, thanks for your comment.

Comment: An idea, though: Try e.g. [OS Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/os-monitor/com.eolwral.osmonitor). Keep it open on the network tab. Wait until the "un.org" (or its IP) turns up somewhere for "remote", and check what app did connect there. Of course, if it just does so once a day, it might not be the best way...